# Python Sum lookup dynamic array table with df column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I wish to create a table like the below:

| ValueX | ValueY | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.203627201 | 3.803627201 | 0.026721649 |
| 3.803627201 | 7.403627201 | 0.007943925 |
| 7.403627201 | 11.0036272 | 0.012526994 |
| 11.0036272 | 14.6036272 | 0.005983166 |

ValueX & Y essentially come from binning the column below and I wish to sum all the corresponding values when between these values (I have provided the excel formula below for extra information)

I'm trying to find a way that pandas or numpy can create the sum without needing a loop, but if I need to loop, happy to hear some thoughts for speed. In some datasets the [ValueX] array could be >30 in length (in the example I have provided there is only 4 but is generally 15-20) and likewise the time stamps in the main data could be +15000 on the bigger sets, thus basic looping will take time.

So my solution will need to be array based, or looped obviously, based on the length of the lookup table and the length of the main data.

=SUMIFS([Value_toSum],[ValuesWhereXYcomefrom],">=" & ValueX(A1),[ValuesWhereXYcomefrom],"<" & ValueY(B1))

| time | Value0 | Value1 | Value2 | ValuesWhereXYcomefrom | Value_toSum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 41.43 | 6.579482077 |  |  | 0.00531021 |
| 2 | 41.650002 | 6.756817908 | 46.72466411 | 6.915187703 | 0.001200456 |
| 3 | 41.700001 | 6.221966706 | 11.64727001 | 1.871959552 | 0.000959257 |
| 4 | 41.740002 | 6.230847055 | 46.92753343 | 7.531485368 | 0.006228989 |
| 5 | 42 | 6.637399856 | 8.031374656 | 1.210018204 | 0.010238095 |
| 6 | 42.43 | 7.484894608 | 16.24547568 | 2.170434793 | -0.007777563 |
| 7 | 42.099998 | 7.595291765 | 38.73871244 | 5.100358702 | 0.003562993 |
| 8 | 42.25 | 7.567457423 | 37.07538953 | 4.899319211 | 0.01088755 |
| 9 | 42.709999 | 8.234795546 | 64.27986403 | 7.805884636 | 0.005151042 |
| 10 | 42.93 | 8.369526407 | 24.72700129 | 2.954408659 | -0.003028209 |
| 11 | 42.799999 | 8.146653099 | 61.52243361 | 7.55186613 | 0 |
| 12 | 42.799999 | 8.060386469 | 4.069816054 | 0.504915747 | 0.007943925 |
| 13 | 43.139999 | 8.35486004 | 24.02202482 | 2.875215708 | 0.005099722 |
| 14 | 43.360001 | 8.344303896 | 65.69597232 | 7.87315193 | -0.003228782 |
| 15 | 43.220001 | 8.354012136 | 59.0376027 | 7.066975932 | -0.005090259 |
| 16 | 43 | 8.619463036 | 52.3941269 | 6.078583629 | 0.010232535 |
| 17 | 43.439999 | 9.080868488 | 42.93689619 | 4.728280808 | 0.002302072 |
| 18 | 43.540001 | 8.867340897 | 57.81235164 | 6.51969427 | 0.003445062 |
| 19 | 43.689999 | 8.181615293 | 7.747858006 | 0.946983906 | 0.002288899 |
| 20 | 43.790001 | 7.969474934 | 11.37454783 | 1.427264396 | 0.005023909 |
| 21 | 44.009998 | 7.692703917 | 70.51485899 | 9.166459512 | -0.001817723 |
| 22 | 43.93 | 7.862134791 | 1.600944501 | 0.203627201 | 0.001365855 |
| 23 | 43.990002 | 7.823998385 | 19.07940961 | 2.438575351 | 0.002273198 |
| 24 | 44.09 | 7.809313794 | 82.27449155 | 10.53543163 | -0.007711499 |
| 25 | 43.75 | 8.554266599 | 38.11043116 | 4.455137179 | -0.002971451 |
| 26 | 43.619999 | 8.606167168 | 90.18746868 | 10.47940005 | -0.011462632 |
| 27 | 43.119999 | 9.179483965 | 24.77124597 | 2.6985445 | 0.005102064 |
| 28 | 43.34 | 8.759390665 | 71.79460753 | 8.196301578 | 0.000461491 |
| 29 | 43.360001 | 8.729639563 | 16.1530103 | 1.850363945 | -0.002767505 |

Comment: I Should also add I have the ability to create the "Bins", my question is simply around how to best handle the SumIFs python function.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the data is given as a pandas DataFrame `df`, and that `bins` is a list of bin boundaries, e.g.:

```
bins = [0.203627201, 3.803627201, 7.403627201, 11.0036272, 14.6036272]
```

then the following should work:

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df["ValuesWhereXYcomefrom"], bins))["Value_toSum"].sum()
```

Comment: worked great! Even learnt a new library function (cut), thank you!

If I wanted to sum when values greater than 0:

df.groupby(pd.cut(df["ValuesWhereXYcomefrom"], bins))["Value_toSum"].sum(df["Value_toSum"]>0) .....?

Comment: Use  `df[df[”Value_toSum”] > 0]` instead of `df`.