# Python Lookup - Mapping Dynamic Ranges (fast)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, bisect

This is an extension to a question I posted earlier: [Python Sum lookup dynamic array table with df column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66947324/python-sum-lookup-dynamic-array-table-with-df-column)

I'm currently investigating a way to efficiently map a decision variable to a dataframe. The main DF and the lookup table will be dynamic in length (+15,000 lines and +20 lines, respectively). Thus was hoping not to do this with a loop, but happy to hear suggestions.

The DF (DF1) will mostly look like the following, where I would like to lookup/search for the decision.

Where the decision value is found on a separate DF (DF0).

For Example: the first DF1["ValuesWhereXYcomefrom"] value is 6.915 which is between 3.8>=(value)>7.4 on the key table and thus the corresponding value DF0["Decision"] is -1. The process then repeats until every line is mapped to a decision.

I was thinking to use the python bisect library, but have not prevailed to any working solution and also working with a loop. Now I'm wondering if I am looking at the problem incorrectly as mapping and looping 15k lines is time consuming.

Example Main Data (DF1):

| time | Value0 | Value1 | Value2 | ValuesWhereXYcomefrom | Value_toSum | Decision Map |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 41.43 | 6.579482077 |  |  | 0.00531021 |  |
| 2 | 41.650002 | 6.756817908 | 46.72466411 | 6.915187703 | 0.001200456 | -1 |
| 3 | 41.700001 | 6.221966706 | 11.64727001 | 1.871959552 | 0.000959257 | -1 |
| 4 | 41.740002 | 6.230847055 | 46.92753343 | 7.531485368 | 0.006228989 | 1 |
| 5 | 42 | 6.637399856 | 8.031374656 | 1.210018204 | 0.010238095 | -1 |
| 6 | 42.43 | 7.484894608 | 16.24547568 | 2.170434793 | -0.007777563 | -1 |
| 7 | 42.099998 | 7.595291765 | 38.73871244 | 5.100358702 | 0.003562993 | -1 |
| 8 | 42.25 | 7.567457423 | 37.07538953 | 4.899319211 | 0.01088755 | -1 |
| 9 | 42.709999 | 8.234795546 | 64.27986403 | 7.805884636 | 0.005151042 | 1 |
| 10 | 42.93 | 8.369526407 | 24.72700129 | 2.954408659 | -0.003028209 | -1 |
| 11 | 42.799999 | 8.146653099 | 61.52243361 | 7.55186613 | 0 | 1 |

Example KeyTable (DF0):

| ValueX | ValueY | SUM | Decision |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.203627201 | 3.803627201 | 0.040294925 | -1 |
| 3.803627201 | 7.403627201 | 0.031630668 | -1 |
| 7.403627201 | 11.0036272 | 0.011841521 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would go about this, assuming your first DataFrame is called `df` and your second is `decision`:

```
def map_func(x):
    for i in range(len(decision)):
        try:
            if x < decision["ValueY"].iloc[i]:
                return decision["Decision"].iloc[i]
        except Exception:
            return np.nan
df["decision"] = df["ValuesWhereXYcomefrom"].apply(lambda x: map_func(x))
```

This will create a new row in your DataFrame called "decision" that contains the looked up value. You can then just query it:

```
df.decision.iloc[row]
```